# Cross-compile V8 with RISC-V toolchain

Tags: cross-compiling, v8, riscv

Does anyone know how to cross-compile V8 for RISC-V? I would like to run V8 on the RISC-V qemu.

I've already built V8 for x64 and installed RISC-V toolchains.

There are some documents for cross-compiling for ARM. However, those for RISC-V don't seem to be enough or exist. Any kind of help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

All cross-compilation works the same, using the `target_arch` GN arg. Specifically, use `gn args out/riscv` (or wherever you want to place your build output) to specify (at least):

```
target_cpu = "riscv64"
v8_target_cpu = "riscv64"
```

You may need `use_clang = false` to make it pick up your system-installed toolchain; I haven't tried it. Of course you can set additional build args to taste, e.g. `is_debug = false` for Release-mode performance.